# how can I change an entire row in my database to change l into Left, and r into right

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am building a database from scratch, and I have close to 20,000 entries.  I have just realized that I in my column `lr` indicating left and right, I would like the entries to be "Left and "Right" instead of `l` and `R`.  I could just go back and retype them, but with almost 2,000 entries in this column, I am trying to find an easier way.  I am thinking I need something similar to this statement, but this does not work. any ideas?

```
USE camdb;
SELECT * FROM camtable;
UPDATE camtable
SET lr = "Left" WHERE lr = "L";
SET lr = "Right" WHERE lr = "R";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE camtable SET lr = "Left" WHERE lr = "L";
UPDATE camtable SET lr = "Right" WHERE lr = "R";
```

Comment: that worked, Im glad I was at least close to having it right, now if I can just get a grasp on my jQuery, I'll be doing good.

Answer (score 1):

you can write two update statement

```
UPDATE camtable SET lr = "Left" WHERE lr = "L";
```

and

```
UPDATE camtable SET SET lr = "Right" WHERE lr = "R";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why using 2 Update statement? If it can be done from using single update statement.

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e504/1)**

**Below is the Update Statement :**

```
USE camdb;
update camtable
   set LR = Case LR when 'L' then 'Left'
                    when 'R' then 'Right' 
            End
 where LR in ('L','R');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track but your syntax was a little off.

You do not need the `SELECT` statement unless you want to show all the data right before it is edited. You also need to use two `UPDATE` statements to change L to Left and R to Right.

Try this:

```
USE camdb;
UPDATE camtable
SET lr = "Left" WHERE lr = "L";
UPDATE camtable
SET lr = "Right" WHERE lr = "R";
```